# Quote from the Chazzon Ish about "Mizrachim"

Tags: chazon-ish, zionism

I was having a discussion with someone tonight who quoted in the name of the Chazzon Ish that the "problem" with the "mizrachi" community (A very large group of Orthodox Jews in Israel that are also proud Zionist have this "title" put to them) is that they don't strive for "perfection" (in their limud haTorah, Avodas HaShem, davening, middos, etc.) Did the Chazzon Ish ever say such a thing? If so, is it recorded anywhere? What did he mean by this?

It was quite surprising that these words would come from such a great chacham and seem to be at best lashon hara if not motzei shem rah on a large group of klal yisrael where you can of course find many (or perhaps if not all of them) that strive for perfection in being a Jew like many (if not all) Orthodox Jews try to do or wish for, etc.

Comment: If it helps, I heard this directly from a local Talmid Hakham. I don't remember if he cited a sefer; but, I thought it might add credence to the question to include my personal experience.

Comment: I would note that even if he did say it that this is not really particularly relevant 70 years after he said it (or however long it was). As individuals in addition to groups can change. That is, what may (or may not) have been true about a group decades ago is no proof of its contemporary behavior, and IMHO one who cites these sorts of statements, accurate or not, is putting words into the gadol's mouth by applying his statement to a setting that he didnt necessarily intend.

Comment: Not quite to the point, but indicative. Take a look at http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52890&st=&pgnum=91&hilite=

Comment: @Lee So this "Talmid Hakham" thought it was also okay to speak lashon hara or motzei shem rah?

Comment: @Yehoshua I think it's probably best for us all to take a hard look at what was *actually* stated/written/intended before coming to any conclusions.

Comment: @Lee absolutely! In it's presented form though it's a good example of the sinas chinam we find now a days. The way the person said it over would not be the way a Gadol or any Jew should speak that's why we need to get to the bottom of it.